# Jquery dialog, or jqdialog in MVC application continues through to contoller action before a response

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog that I want to appear when a view doesn't contain an expected answer.
The problem is the code execution continues to the controller action before a response is accepted by the dialog.

Here is the javascript code for the submit button.

```
$('#Submit1').click(function () {
        var yes = $("#yes");
        var no = $("#no");
        var errorInd = $("#errorMsg");

        if ((yes[0] == undefined || yes[0] == null) && no[0] == undefined || no[0] == null) {
            var answer = $("#answer");
            var answer2 = $("#answer2");
            if (answer[0] != undefined && answer2[0] != undefined) {
                if (answer[0].value == "" && answer2[0].value == "") {
                    errorInd[0].style.display = '';
                    $("#errorMsg").css({ visibility: 'visible' });
                }
            }
        } else if (!yes[0].checked && !no[0].checked) {
            // alert dialog
         $.jqDialog.confirm("Are you sure want to continue?", 
                        function () { CallSubmit();       },  // callback function for 'YES' button  
                        function () { alert("This intrusive alert says you clicked NO"); }  // callback function for 'NO' button            );
         //   $('#errorMessage').dialog('open');


        );
```

The submit button is within a form in this view code.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAnswer", "Home", FormMethod.Post )) { %>
  <% foreach (var question in Model)  { %>

    <% if (question.AnswerType== 1) { %>

     <% Html.RenderPartial("YesNo", question);} %>
    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 0) {  Html.RenderPartial("TextView", question);} %>
    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 2) { Html.RenderPartial("TwoTextView", question); } %>
    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 3) { Html.RenderPartial("TextOnlyView", question); } %>
    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 5) { Html.RenderPartial("RadioListView", question); } %>

    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 7) { Html.RenderPartial("SingleDateTimeView", question); } %>

    <% else if (question.AnswerType == 6) { Html.RenderPartial("DateRangeView", question); } %>
      <input type="hidden"  name="qNumber" value='<%: question.QuestionID %>' />
      <input type="hidden"  name="answerType" value='<%: question.AnswerType%>' />


       <% } %>

  <div id="errorMsg" class="errorMsg"  style="display:none">* select yes or no</div>
  <input type="hidden"  name="groupCount" value='<%: Model.Count %>' /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Next" id="Submit1" name="submit"   />  
<%--    <li><%: Html.ActionLink("Error Message Dialog", "ErrorInAnswer", "Home", new { @class = "modalDlg", title = "Error Message" })%></li>
--%>
```

<% } %>

I have spent alot of time on this any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Traci

Answer (score 0):

From the code posted above, looks like you are handling the submit  (calling CallSubmit) once the user selects OK/Yes, hence return false at the end of the event handler.

Change:

```
$('#Submit1').click(function () {
 .
 .
 .
 .
 //You existing code.

});
```

to

```
$('#Submit1').click(function () {
 .
 .
 .
 .
 //You existing code.
 return false;
});
```